# Roots of $Y^3 - Y + 1$ in $\mathbb{F}_3[Y]/(Y^3- Y^2 +1)$

Tags: ring-theory

I just solved this problem and didn't find it to be a problem at all, that why I think I overlooked something, but I can't think of anything.

I just argued that $Y^3 \equiv Y^2 - 1 \quad (\textrm{mod} \quad (Y^3- Y^2 +1))$.

So $Y^3 - Y + 1 \equiv Y^2 - Y = Y(Y-1)$ and I find the roots to be $0$ and $1$ in  $\mathbb{F}_3[Y]/(Y^3- Y^2 +1)$.

Is this correct?

Comment: It's not at all correct. If you substitute $0,1$ into your original polynomial, you can see immediately that both are not roots! What has the equivalence of polynomials modulo something got to do with the roots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\ff{\mathbb{F}}$Firstly, is $Y^3 - Y^2 + 1$ irreducible in $\ff_3[Y]$? If so, then you have a field extension of $\ff_3$, and let $r$ be a root of the polynomial in the field extension.

Secondly, what is the degree of the field extension, and what do you know about finite fields? All finite fields of the same characteristic and size are isomorphic (because the algebraic closure has a unique field of that size since $x^{3^3-1} = 1$ for nonzero $x$ in any such field by Lagrange's theorem).

So we expect to find all irreducible cubics' roots in any given degree 3 extension. Notice that $(x+1)^3 - (x+1) + 1 = x^3 - x + 1$ for any $x$ in the field extension, so you already know how to find all 3 roots if you have any one. $0$ is not a root, contrary to your claim, so immediately $1,2$ are not either. So you only have to try $ar^2+br$ for all possible $a,b \in [0..2]$, using the fact that $r^3 = r^2 - 1$. There could be further tricks but this works.

Comment: Thanks, I learned a great deal from this!

Comment: @Miriam: You're welcome! Note that by fixing the algebraic closure (which is unique up to isomorphism), we can see that for any irreducible cubic, any root will generate an extension of degree 3, and since there is only one degree 3 extension in the algebraic closure, this extension contains all the other roots too. For other kinds of field extensions, this is usually false, since extending by one root does not usually generate all the other roots. But quadratic extensions always generate the second root since their sum is in the base field.